# Characteristics of a Non-Hermitian Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How does one determine if a non-hermitian matrix is positive definite, positive semi-definite, negative definite, etc...? Everything I find is for Hermitian matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by "positive definite"? If you mean that $x^\ast Ax$ is real nonnegative for all *complex* vectors $x$, then $A$ is necessarily Hermitian. In fact, if $A$ is a matrix such that $x^\ast Ax\in\mathbb R$ for all complex vectors $x$, then $A$ is necessarily Hermitian.

Comment: @user1551 That is where my confusion comes. My professor asked us to show  the quadratic form of $$\begin{bmatrix} 8 &  -6\\ 3 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$ is psd, sd, nd, nsd, or indefinite, but it is my understanding this only holds for hermitian matrices

Comment: @user1551 The only thing I can think of is to find the quadratic form and then find an equivalent symmetric matrix and use the eigenvalues of this matrix to show psd etc.

Comment: What your professor concerns are probably quadratic forms over the real field. In this case, we can define the "positive definiteness" of a non-symmetric **real** matrix $A$ as $x^TAx>0$ for all **real** vectors $x$. Therefore $A$ is positive definite if and only if the symmetric matrix $A+A^T$ is positive definite in the usual sense. In other words, one may verify whether $A$ is PD, PSD, etc. by looking at the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$.

Comment: To the OP. You obtained $2$ answers. Had you read them? The use in this website is, if one is satisfied with the answer, to upvote or to give the green ticket; otherwise one reports what is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are looking at real matrices $A$ and real vectors $v$, use the facts that (i) $v^TAv=v^T((A+A^T)/2)v$ for all $A,v$ (ii) $A+A^T$ and $(A+A^T)/2$
are symmetric (iii) a matrix is positive-definite, negative-definite, positive-semi-definiteor negative semi-definite iff that matrix multiplied by a positive number is positive-definite, negative-definite, positive-semi-definite or negative semi-definite respectively, all that we have to do is apply a test for positive-definiteness, etc. for symmeric matrices to the symmetric matrix $A+A^T.$ $$*$$
Warning: We use the definitions that a matrix $M$ is positive definite if $v^TAv>0$ for all $v \ne 0$ and posive  semi-definite if $v^TMv \ge 0$ for all $v$ with similar definitions for negative definite and negative semi definite. In the older literature "positive semi-definite" was often defined as " $v^TMv \ge 0$ for all $v$ and $M$ is not positive definite." We do NOT impose that additional equirement. For us,the only defining condition for being positive semi definite is $v^TMv \ge 0$ for all $v$. $$*$$ It is possible to give tests for these conditions in terms of eigenvalues of the matrix. We do not do so.  Finding the eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix requires solving an algebraic equation of degree $n.$ $$*$$  An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is positive-definite iff in the matrix $A+A^T$ every upper left $i \times i$ block has positive determinant for $1 \le i \le n.$ $$*$$ An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is negative -definite iff in the matrix $A+A^T$ every upper left $i \times i$ block has positive determinant if $i$ is even and negative determinant if $i$ is odd, for $1 \le i \le n.$ $$*$$ An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is positive semi definite iff in the matrix $A+A^T$ every principal minor of order i is $\ge 0$ for $1 \le i \le n.$ $$*$$ An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is negative semi definite iff in the matrix $A+A^T$ every principal minor of order i is $\ge 0$ if $i$ is even and $\le 0$ if $i$ is odd for $1 \le i \le n.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (be eventually non-hermitian); as stated in other posts, the first thing to do is to calculate $B=A+A^*$. Now, to check if $B$ is $>0,<0,\geq 0,\leq 0$, then there are $2$ methods.

1. (The worst one)  calculate the $n$ (upper-left) principal determinants of $B$. The complexity is $\approx n^4/4$. Unfortunately, this allows to conclude only if $B>0,<0$. Otherwise it is necessary to calculate all the principal determinants !!
2. Calculate an approximation of the (real) eigenvalues of $B$. The complexity is $\approx$ from  $10$ to $15n^3$. It is necessary to check carefully the number of zero-eigenvalues.
3. Now, if you want to know if $B$ is $>0$ (resp. $<0$), then the best method is to calculate the Cholesky decomposition of $B$ (resp. $-B$). If the algorithm gives an output, then the answer is yes; if you obtain an error message, then the answer is no. The complexity is $\approx n^3/2$.